# Is the refresh token provide by firebase the same refresh token from google?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, refresh-token

thanks to take time and give me some help

This is my situation:
I have a web application that use google calendar api, but the user let say userA only have access to read the calendars, to create an event in the calendar I have to impersonate the request to the google api and send an auth_token with write grant, let say UserB (the userb exist in the database, and I save there access_token and refresh token) provided by firebase

My question is, can I use, the refresh token firebase response to refresh the access_token? or that refresh token will not work with the google oath api?

Thanks for your help any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use the `refresh token` from one `token` to refresh another `token`.

The `refresh token` must be requested when the OAuth 2.0 flow is started. The returned OAuth 2.0 Token will include a number of items, which include the `Access Token` and optionally the `Refresh Token`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will not try to cross refresh token, what I need is refresh an access token out side of firebase but using the refresh token firebase provide me when the user made the login I save his/her refresh token then i will Call this endpoint https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token using the refresh token firebase give me. I try a lot of and always give me invalid grant access.